# How to keep master page on page reload in HTML using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

In my application  i have declared ng-app in Master.html and added all script, stylesheet references in it
this is my master page

```
<html  ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>

    <script src="../Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/AngularServices/App.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
                       <li><a href="/main/Group"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Group</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/main/Member"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Member</a></li>
 <section class="content">
                              <div ng-view></div>
                            </section>

</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute'])

mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/main/Group', { templateUrl: '/Portal/Group.html', controller: 'GroupController' }),
    $routeProvider.when('/main/Member', { templateUrl: '/Portal/Member.html', controller: 'MemberController' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

// group 
mainApp.controller('GroupController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/APIGroup/GetGroupDetails').then(function (result) {
        $scope.group = result.data;
    });
});
```

Group.html

```
<div ng-controller="GroupController">
    <div class="row">
<h1>Welcome to group</h1>
my content here
 </div>
</div>
```

when i execute master page and if click group link group.html form opening inside master page  my url like this

```
http://localhost:50810/main/chitGroup
```

but if reload page here  am getting error  as

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
```

Master page not applying to how to fix this

Comment: Refer to [this guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

Answer (score 0):

In your `angular.app` you have `ngRoute` to handle your states for create `Single Page Application`.

`ngRoute` need to pass the state names correctly as `ng-href="#!/main/Group"`, that because when you use `ngRoute` the url changed automaticly to `http://localhost:50810/#!/`

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
```

> This error because you redirect to `http://localhost:50810` to find `/main/Group` which not exist.

Comment: i changed like this     <li><a ng-href="#!/main/chitGroup"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Chit Group</a></li>
                                    <li><a ng-href="#!/main/ChitMember"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Chit Member</a></li>     but it not working  am not getting error but my html page was not loading , my url like this http://localhost:50810/Portal/Master.html#!%2Fmain%2FchitGroup

Comment: i didn't see it, do you want use `html5Mode` in your application?

Comment: i have given in app.js      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: if you using `html5Mode` first you should add `<base href="/">` in the head of your `html`, second do you use `asp` or `php` ?

Comment: refer [page-not-found-error-while-reloading-after-removing-in-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285431/page-not-found-error-while-reloading-after-removing-in-url/44286005#44286005)